# How configure hibernate cascade for some field?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have same problem when update my `User` object. I want update `User`, `Work` but not `Image`. Relation user-image is one-to-one.
For update used hibernate method `update(Object obj)`. Think that this can solve with use @Cascade but I can't find how? Can help me? Thanks.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private Image image;
    private Work work;
    //getter setter
}

@Entity
public class Work {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String info;
    private String phone;
    //getter setter
}
@Entity
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String url;
    private String name;
    //setter getter
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Cascade(CascadeType.MERGE)` or `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)` on `work` or `getWork`